# How can I use AutoHotkay to click "next page" and take a screenshot and repeat until I terminate the process?

Tags: loops, screenshot, autohotkey

I want AHK to do the following:
1. Click in a specific location on the screen
2. Take a snippet of a pre-selected area
3. Save the snippet
4. Repeat the process until I press the "S" key (stop)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MouseMove command to move it then send a click. After that you would just make it press the hotkeys for the screenshot and use the MouseClickDrag to form the rectangle. Then you make the script do ctrl+s to save it, and loop that. That's what I would've done. If you want, I could try to make a script for template.

Comment: Yes, that would be incredible! I'm going to give it my first try today at making a script, as I have finally read through the manual (as an educational experience). However, I would love to get started applying that code immediately, since the number of pages I need to make is now around 3,000.